# Is every commutative ring a limit of noetherian rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, noetherian, limits-colimits

Let $\mathsf{Noeth}$ be the category of noetherian rings, viewed as a full subcategory of the category $\mathsf{CRing}$ of commutative rings with one.

Let $A$ be in $\mathsf{CRing}$.

> **Question 1.** Is there a functor from a small category to $\mathsf{Noeth}$ whose limit in $\mathsf{CRing}$ is $A$?

(I know that there is a functor from a small category to $\mathsf{Noeth}$ whose *colimit* is $A$.)

Let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism in $\mathsf{CRing}$ such that the map
$$
\circ f:\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(B,C)\to\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(A,C)
$$ 
sending $g$ to $g\circ f$ is bijective for all $C$ in $\mathsf{Noeth}$.

> **Question 2.** Does this imply that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Yes to Question 1 would imply yes to Question 2.

> **Question 3.** Does the inclusion functor $\iota:\mathsf{Noeth}\to\mathsf{CRing}$ commute with colimits? That is, if $A\in\mathsf{Noeth}$ is the colimit of a functor $\alpha$ from a small category to $\mathsf{Noeth}$, is $A$ naturally isomorphic to the colimit of $\iota\circ\alpha$?

Yes to Question 2 would imply yes to Question 3, and yes to Question 3 would imply that many colimits, and in particular many binary coproducts, do *not* exist in $\mathsf{Noeth}$: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338437/660) of Martin Brandenburg.

---

One may try to attack the first question as follows:

Let $A$ be in $\mathsf{CRing}$ and $I$ the set of those ideals $\mathfrak a$ of $A$ such that $A/\mathfrak a$ is noetherian. Then $I$ is an ordered set, and thus can be viewed as a category. We can form the limit of the $A/\mathfrak a$ with $\mathfrak a\in I$, and we have a natural morphism from $A$ to this limit. I'd be interested in knowing if this morphism is bijective.

Comment: I guess by question 1 you mean if there's a functor $F$ from a small category to ${\bf Noeth}$ such that $A$ is the limit of $EF$. ($E:{\bf Noeth} \rightarrow {\bf CRing}$ is the inclusion functor.)

Comment: @sqtrat - Thanks! Yes. I've added "in $\mathsf{CRing}$". I hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: Doesn't question 2 follow from the fact that a ring is *co*limit of noetherian rings ?(plug in $C_i$, where $\varinjlim C_i =A$ to get $id_A$ has an antecedent, then plug in $D_i$ where $\varinjlim D_i = B$ to get that the inverse we get was a $2$-sided inverse) (I used $\varinjlim$ to denote the colimit, because in fact we can choose the colimit to be a "direct limit")

Comment: @Max - Sorry I don't understand. For the first step, here is how I try to follow your argument. (Let me use lim and colim.) You replace (I believe) $A$ and $C$ by $\text{colim }C_i$ with $C_i$ noetherian. You get $$\circ f:\text{Hom}(B,\text{colim }C_i)\to\text{Hom}(\text{colim }C_i,\text{colim }C_i).$$ This gives a map $$\phi:\text{Hom}(B,\text{colim }C_i)\to\lim\text{Hom}(C_i,\text{colim }C_i).$$ Let $c_i:C_i\to\text{colim }C_i$ be the coprojection. Then $$(c_i)\in\lim\text{Hom}(C_i,\text{colim }C_i)$$ corresponds to the identity of $\text{colim }C_i$...

Comment: You're claiming, it seems to me, that $(c_i)$ is in the image of $\phi$. Is that right?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard : sorry I actually wrote it down and it didn't work

Comment: @Max - Don't worry! It happens to me all the time!

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/323136/461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put this off the unanswered list:

Laurent Moret-Bailly has shown at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323136/is-every-commutative-ring-a-limit-of-noetherian-rings) that the answer is "No" for all three questions here.